# When using NFS on Vagrant, composer update error: addClassMap() must be of the type array, integer given

Tags: vagrant, composer-php, nfs, vagrant-windows

Whenever I try to run `composer update` within my Laravel Homestead Vagrant VirtualBox, I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::addClassMap() must be of the type array, integer given, called in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php on line 760
```

But then if I remove the following two lines from the `folders` section of my Homestead.yaml and run `homestead.bat reload --provision` to reload the VM, `composer update` works again.

```
type: "nfs"
mount_options: ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']
```

I really want to leave NFS enabled because it substantially speeds up one of my apps.

How can I fix Composer?

P.S. See [WinNFSd](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd/tree/f703e8996bbb01312755b554689cb910b92426b9)